# attaching an picture to an image view

Tags: android, android-layout

attaching an picture to an image view

```
android:src="@drawable/image name"
```

Comment: please put some more code

Comment: here is what it should look like: should look like: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=90D26B3C24DAF89C%21123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an `ImageView` you can set the red circular image as a `background` and the main image as the `src` with proper `scaleType`.

Or else your two ImageView in a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

But you need to make sure that the color beyond the red boundary should be opaque and filled with the back ground color.
Its just like hiding the extra part of the inner image with the image on the top.

Added Code :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView_main_image"
        android:background="@drawable/your_main_image_here"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView_background_image"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView_main_image"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_main_image"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView_main_image"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView_main_image"
        android:background="@drawable/your_border_image_here"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide some code

Comment: no it did not work - the image completely overshadowed the frame

Comment: because of the border image. As its totally transparent. You need to fill the outter part of the border with color, so that it becomes opaque and hides the below region of the main image

Comment: @gaerdarrd check the image!

Comment: I downloaded and added the image you posted to my project , and used it as the background image. still didn't work

Comment: Yes it did work for me!

Comment: can you email me your code ?

Comment: or can you upload it some where so i can get it ?

Comment: wow it worked.. never mind.. i had a bug!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fragme drawable as `background` in the ImageView and the image itself as `src` of the ImageView, like so

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/frame"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
```